# file upload to azure file share not working with bigger file

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, hapi.js, azure-files

i am trying to upload large file(0 to 100mb) to azure file share using this @azure/storage-file-share node Js client library.

small files less than 4 MB works good, but more that that is thowing an error (contentLength must be > 0 and <= 4194304 bytes)

My payload is in readable stream and and i am using method uploadRange in the library

here is the below code

```js
{
        method: "POST",
        path: `${apiBase}/mount`,
        config: {
          description: "uploadFile",
          tags: ["api", "file"],
          notes: ["upload a file"],
          auth: {
            strategy: "jwt",
            mode: options.session.auth,
            access: {
              scope: options.session.scope,
            },
          },
          payload: {
            maxBytes: 1024 * 1024 * 200,
            multipart: true,
            parse: true,
            output: "stream",
            allow: "multipart/form-data",
          },
          timeout: {
            server: 10 * 60 * 1000,
            socket: 12 * 60 * 1000,
          },

          response: {
            status: {
              200: Joi.object({
                status: Joi.string(),
                fileUrl: Joi.string(),
                date: Joi.number(),
              }),
              422: Joi.object({
                statusCode: Joi.number().integer(),
                error: Joi.string(),
                message: Joi.string(),
              }),
              503: Joi.object({
                statusCode: Joi.number().integer(),
                error: Joi.string(),
                message: Joi.string(),
              }),
            },
          },
          handler: async (request, h) => {
            if (!request.auth.credentials) {
              throw Boom.unauthorized("unexpected unauthorized error");
            }
            try {
              const azureDirectory = azure.sanitizeContainerName(
                request.auth.credentials.userId
              );
              const azureFileStream = request.payload.file;
              const r = await azure.uploadFileToVolume({
                azureFileServiceClient: options.azureFileServiceClient,
                azureFileVolumeMount: options.azureFileVolumeMount,
                azureFileStream,
                azureDirectory,
              });
              if (r.errorCode) {
                throw Boom.badData(
                  `file upload error due to azure error ${r.errorCode}` +
                    `\n${JSON.stringify(r)}`
                );
              }

              return h.response({
                status: "ok",
                fileUrl:
                  options.azureFileServiceClient.url +
                  azureDirectory +
                  // encode file name
                  `/${encodeURIComponent(azureFileStream.hapi.filename)}`,
                date: new Date(r.lastModified).getTime(),
              });
            } catch (e) {
              throw Boom.serverUnavailable(`file upload error ${e}`);
            }
          },
        },
      }
      
      
exports.uploadFileToVolume = async ({
  azureFileServiceClient,
  azureFileVolumeMount,
  azureFileStream,
  azureDirectory,
}) => {
  const directoryClient = await azureFileServiceClient
    .getShareClient(azureFileVolumeMount)
    .getDirectoryClient(azureDirectory);

  if (!(await directoryClient.exists())) {
    // create azure directory by userid if not exists
    await azureFileServiceClient
      .getShareClient(azureFileVolumeMount)
      .createDirectory(azureDirectory);
  }

  const content = azureFileStream._data;
  const fileName = encodeURIComponent(azureFileStream.hapi.filename);
  const fileClient = directoryClient.getFileClient(fileName);
  await fileClient.create(content.length);

  return await fileClient.uploadRange(content, 0, content.length);

};
```

can any one help me to get the right method in the library to send the files, i tried to use uploadStream abut it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this error is because the maximum content size allowed for an `uploadRange` is 4MB. `uploadRange` operation maps to [`Put Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-range) REST API operation and the limitation is from the REST API side (see description for `Range or x-ms-range` in request headers section).

What you have to do is read chunks of your content and then call `uploadRange` method repeatedly using those chunks. When reading chunks, you have to ensure that the maximum size of the chunk you read does not exceed 4MB.

Comment: a c# example that might help you create a javascript version https://stackoverflow.com/a/64031613/74585