# Why is azure file share openReadAsync() breaks when file over 4mb?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, streamreader, azure-file-share

I'm trying to openReadAsync() csv file from azure file share. But if the file is over 4mb ReadLineAsync() returns whole file as [���������������������������], instead of returning first line.

Here is the code i use to create stream

```
var dir = GetCloudDirectory(type, isImport);
var cloudFile = dir.GetFileClient(fileName);
var stream = await cloudFile.OpenReadAsync();
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var firstLine = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
```

Any ideas how to debug this or what could be the problem?

Comment: As a note, the � is known as the Unicode _Replacement Character_.  It indicates that the character doesn't map to a known character that can be rendered: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block).  That doesn't answer your question, but it may provide some insight.

Comment: Found that the issue is not the download but the upload: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031612/uploading-to-azure-file-storage-fails-with-large-files

Answer (score 0):

> To read the content of a CSV file from Azure Storage, you can use the `CsvReader` class from the CsvHelper library.

**Step-1:Uploaded `.csv` file in Azure File Share**

[image]

**Step-2: Here is How  i am able to Read file using openReadAsync()**

> You need to install the CsvHelper library
> **CsvHelper**

**Program.cs**

```
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares;
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares.Models;
using CsvHelper;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "Your_Connection_String";
        string shareName = "Your_Share_Name";
        string fileName = "Your_CSV_File.csv";

        try
        {
            ShareServiceClient serviceClient = new ShareServiceClient(connectionString);
            ShareClient shareClient = serviceClient.GetShareClient(shareName);
            ShareDirectoryClient directoryClient = shareClient.GetDirectoryClient("");
            ShareFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.GetFileClient(fileName);

            if (await fileClient.ExistsAsync())
            {
                Stream stream = await fileClient.OpenReadAsync();

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
                {
                    // Read the CSV records and process them
                    var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();
                    foreach (var record in records)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(record);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not found.");
            }
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An unexpected error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**
[image]